# Varnish Backend Handling

Tags: nginx, varnish

I am facing a rather tricky issue, where it appears that the varnish is closing the backend connection without waiting for a respones from the backend.

We are using Nginx to serve static content Below is the sequence of messages

Varnish sends POST request to App
App sends back 500 Internal Server Error
Varnish interprets the 500 internal Server Error (to display static error page)
Varnish sends GET request to Nginx server (on the same server) to serve static content
Varnish shows following error message (even though Nginx sends the response successfully within milliseconds)

```
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    38 boot.staticpages 127.0.0.1 82 127.0.0.1 35064
-   BackendStart   127.0.0.1 82
-   FetchError     backend write error: 0 (Success)
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1543420795.016075 5.106813 0.000099
-   BackendClose   38 boot.staticpages
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1543420795.016497 5.107235 0.000422
-   Timestamp      Error: 1543420795.016503 5.107241 0.000005
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 15:59:55 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
```

Varnish then again goes the same Nginx server to display default content.
Nginx sends response and varnish accepts it and sends it back to the customer

It appears that the backend connection gets closed pretty quickly

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: Your varnishlog seems incomplete (only backend request). Are you sure it's not [this](https://ma.ttias.be/varnish-fetcherror-straight-insufficient-bytes/)?

Comment: It's only backend request showing the connection gets closed before the response is received from the backend :( unfortunately it's not what related to the issue mentinoed in the link

Answer (score 0):

We resolve the issue and below is the summary of what the issue was and how we resolved it;

**Issue Summary:**
Varnish is displaying backend fetch error when original POST request results in 500 Internal Error and backend_response is used to GET staticpage customized 500 Internal Server Error Message

**VarnishLog Output** (only relevant message):
It can be seen that Backend is being closed as soon as the request is sent.

```
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    24 boot.staticpages 127.0.0.1 82 127.0.0.1 40696
-   BackendStart   127.0.0.1 82
-   FetchError     backend write error: 0 (Success)
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1543416195.877756 5.116981 0.000046
-   BackendClose   24 boot.staticpages
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1543416195.877888 5.117113 0.000132
-   Timestamp      Error: 1543416195.877892 5.117117 0.000004
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 14:43:15 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
```

**Root Cause:**
Varnish can't retry because there's no body to send anymore.

**Resolution:**
Cache the body of the original request by using std.cache_req_body(10KB);  https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_generated.html#func-cache-req-body